# Why changing part of the private key could still decrypted the message encrypted by pubKey?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm practicing the RSA asymmetric cryptography and found something really strange:changing part of the private key could still decrypted the message!

Here is my steps: (on ubuntu 16.04)

1. generate private key: `openssl genrsa -out private.key`
2. generate public key: `openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout -out pub.key`
3. encrypt a message like "hello world" with pubKey and decrypt with private key.
4. by now everything works fine, the encrypted message could be decoded.
5. then I changed some of the letters in private key(e,g., A->B, i->I, just replace, no append or delete), and try to decrypt the msg again, it passed! but i think it should failed...
6. I then tried to change some other different letters, while, some changes may failed the decode but some not. (I tried the encrypt/decrypt with both nodejs and Java, showing the same result...)

I then try to analyze the structure of the private key to see if I changed some meaningless fields:

- get detail fields with the commands `openssl rsa -in faked_private.key -text -out faked_private.txt`
- compared private.txt with the faked one faked_private.txt.
- there are fields as follows:

  > Private-Key: (2048 bit), modulus, publicExponent, privateExponent, prime1, prime2, exponent1, exponent2, coefficient
- I found that when i changed values of coefficient/privateExponent/prime2, the private key still worked
- But when I changed values of modulus, it failed.

I'm not quite understand the theory inside RSA, but from the basic prime number formula n=p*q, I think at least prime should not be changed.

is there someone who can assist on this issue, and with a simpler answer? (really don't want to go deep into maths...)

thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Your experiment was a good one. There is much redundancy in that particular format of an RSA private key. You should examine the openssl command source code to see why the behavior you've witnessed occurs.

Comment: @JamesKPolk That said, I don't see the added value of validating the integrity of the private key this way. You may want to protect the private key from being read or being replaced. If you *really* need integrity then for goodness sake just store a secure hash value over it.

Comment: Validating the integrity? No, it's simply a good way to understand some of the number theory behind RSA.